# css Problem on positioning IE

Tags: css

i have a problem for my layout... it should be simple but i just won't get it right. It works on firefox but not on IE .... :'(

please do not write some pages of tutorials... its an unique problem ;).

Problem: the div leftBar and rightBar should be resizing to the content. If there is a lot of text, they should have the same height (therefor i used top and bottom on an absolute positioning) the content is all right and it works just the leftBar and the rightBar won't resize... thx for responding, regards marius

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative; width:100px;">
  <div id="leftBar" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; bottom:0px; width:10px;"></div>
  <div id="content" style="position:relative; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;"></div>
  <div id="rightBar" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; bottom:0px; width:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `background-image` on the `div#container` to give it the appearance of both `leftBar` and `rightBar` having equal heights

The other way I can think of is to use javascript and set the heights.

Comment: i thought about that too, but its not the way it should be solved ;)

Comment: have a look at this method: http://woorkup.com/2009/10/11/really-simple-css-trick-for-equal-height-columns/